# Jquery Bootstrap not allowing zero as value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Jquery Bootstrap to add data to MYSQL, but it doesn't allow a value of zero.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        $('.xedit').editable(); 
        $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
            var x = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('data-id');
            var key = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('id');
            var y = $('.input-sm').val();
            var z = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev();
            $.ajax({
                url: "add_preds.php?id="+x+"&pred="+y+"&key="+key,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(s){
                if(s == 'status'){
                $(z).html(y);}
                if(s == 'error') {
                alert('Error Processing your Request!');}
                },
                error: function(e){
                alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
                }
            });

        });     

});
</script>
```

Here is the add_preds.php:

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$pred_org = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['pred']);
$key = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['key']);

//Only numbers
$pred = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $pred_org);

//Fetch user id
$qus = "SELECT id, admin FROM fxweb_users WHERE username = '".htmlentities($_SESSION['username'])."'";
$rus = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qus);
$rowus = mysqli_fetch_array($rus);
$userid = $rowus['id'];
$is_admin = $rowus['admin'];

//Check if match exists
$qm = "SELECT * FROM fxweb_predictiondata WHERE matchid = ".$id." AND userid = ".$userid."";
$rm = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qm);
$rowm = mysqli_fetch_array($rm);
$predhome = $rowm['homescore']; 
$predaway = $rowm['awayscore']; 

//Define date and time
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if ($key == 1 && $pred) {
if ($predhome >= 0) {
//a real user posted a real reply
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fxweb_predictiondata SET homescore=? WHERE matchid=? AND userid=?")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $pred, $id, $userid); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
}
}

if ($key == 1 && !$predhome && !$predaway && $pred) {
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO fxweb_predictiondata (userid, matchid, predtime, homescore) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $userid, $id, $date, $pred); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
}

if ($key == 2 && $pred) {
if ($predaway >= 0 ) {
//a real user posted a real reply
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fxweb_predictiondata SET awayscore=? WHERE matchid=? AND userid=?")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $pred, $id, $userid); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
}
}

if ($key == 2 && !$predaway && !$predhome && $pred) {
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO fxweb_predictiondata (userid, matchid, predtime, awayscore) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $userid, $id, $date, $pred); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
}

//Admin enter match results
if ($key == 3 && $pred && $is_admin = 1) {
if ($predhome >= 0) {
//a real user posted a real reply
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fxweb_matches SET homescore=? WHERE id=?")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $pred, $id); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
}
}



if ($key == 4 && $pred && $is_admin = 1) {
if ($predaway >= 0 ) {
//a real user posted a real reply
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fxweb_matches SET awayscore=? WHERE id=?")) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss', $pred, $id); 
   // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
}
}
```

The script works well, until I try to add a '0' to input, it doesn't allow it and throws the error alert!

Somebody know a fix to this?

Comment: Where is your add_preds.php code ? Error is generated by that .. jquery/bootstrap has got nothing to do with this ..

Comment: Yep i agree, the error should come from PHP side, not JS side. Furthermore, why do you have a GET query out of a POST query (better verbose for a db insertion).

Comment: I have added the php code, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I had an "if" statement in the add_preds.php file, which searched for prediction value:

```
if ($key == 1 && $pred)
```

But it seems that the jquery/Bootstrap is not passing a value if you enter zero (0) in the input field, and therefore the databasequery was unsuccessful!

I simply removed the prediction value from the if statement:

```
if ($key == 1)
```

Then it works fine!

I also changed the "GET" to "POST" in the jquery script, as mentioned in the comments.